# Could not load file or assembly '..' or one of its dependencies.- Add um espaço em branco no web.config volta a funcionar por horas

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, iis

Tenho um painel administrativo feito em webform asp.net C#.
De alguns dias para cá, começou a dar problemas do tipo

```
Could not load file or assembly 'chat_megacorretor.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

O sistema trava, porém basta eu abrir o web.config adicionar um espaço em branco e o site volta a funcionar por horas, mas depois automaticamente trava de novo.

Basta também mudar o nome do arquivo e voltar para o original que volta a funcionar, ou subir o arquivo do projeto para o servidor. Sei que quando faço isso o ASP.Net recompila tudo e por isso ele funciona, porém depois de algumas horas para novamente.

Esse mesmo projeto funcionou por meses, e agora começou a dar problema, recentemente fizemos uma reinstalação do IIS do zero, porém não creio que seja esse o motivo, porque após a reinstalação funcionou por umas 2 semanas. Mas agora começou a dar problema mais uma vez.

No *event view* não encontro nada de interessante, apenas alguns *warnings*.

Que nem sei se são referentes a esse problema em si:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\megacorretor\siga_2008\web.config line 16)
```

e também:

```
Process information: 
    Process ID: 12680 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\admin_Net 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: FileNotFoundException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'CHAT_Megacorretor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=pt-BR, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Siga_2014.admin.Admin.DefineChatsWMB(Cliente iCliente)
   at Siga_2014.admin.Admin.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema está relacionado a referência a .dll `CHAT_Megacorretor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=pt-BR, PublicKeyToken=null` não encontrada.

Reveja as configurações do *pool* que está vinculado a sua aplicação. Talvez a o *pool* da aplicação possa estar sendo reciclada em momentos errados, ou as configurações de "Proteção de Falhas" do *pool* da aplicação, possam estar ocasionando a falha.

## UPDATE

O que me ocorreu agora é que o problemas também pode estar relacionado a versão da sua .dll, se sua .dll (CHAT_Megacorretor) não está no GAC, e sim direto na pasta junto com outras .dlls e você atualizou o site, porém, fez isso sem para o *pool*. Podem ocorrer problemas de referência. Tente parar o pool da aplicação, apagar todos os arquivo da aplicação e republicá-la.

Comment: Aparentemente pode ser isso, estava utilizando o ProcessMonitor e via que o PID mudava toda hora, removi o reclycle e parece que corrigiu. Estou monitorando.
Pq isso acontece?

Comment: As configurações do recycle pool é essencial para um controle fino da sua aplicação (quanto ela vai usar de memória, CPU, etc). O recycle em alguns casos, melhora a performance do seu servidor, porque de tempos em tempos, libera recursos da máquina para sua aplicação. Essas proteções de CPU e Memória são fundamentais pela segurança. Imagina que você está recebendo um ataque, se você não limitar os recursos do servidor para sua aplicação, você não conseguirá acessar a máquina para gerenciá-la.